# How to print currently used random_state in MLPClassifier from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-seed

I use MLPClassifier (sklearn library) for neural network modeling in Python. I don't specified randome_state, but I want to see what random seed is used every time I run my model.

My model's example is below. For now random seed is fixed. I want to remove it from model but I'd like to see what seed was used when I print results.

```
model = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,), max_iter = 600, activation='tanh', 
                  learning_rate = 'adaptive',
                  random_state = 40
                 )
```

Is it possible to print currently used random_state?

The only thing I could find is how to add random seed inside model - I know how to do it and that's not the issue.

I'm curious what random seed would be better for my model and data.

Comment: Of course I tried. I found how to add random seed to model. I know how to do it and that's not the issue.

Comment: I've added info

Comment: Thanks for adding the info. I think this makes the question answerable. However, I hope that your model will not perform much better or worse just depending on the random_state. If so, it would probably hint at other more serious problems.

Comment: yeah, I know about it. but as for now I need to track random seed if it possible.